# Finding average of a sample with single piece of data

Tags: average

Is there anyway possible to guesstimate/estimate the average of a sample if you know just one of the sameple and its position when all available samples are arranged ascendingly and total number of samples.

example:  lets say a student has scored 14.5 out of 25 in an exam in a class test and his rank is 4th out of 80 students, so is there anyway i can make a good approximation of what the average of the test could be?

Comment: Without no more information the answer is probably NO. You must have some additional information.

Comment: Nope there is no additional information and i am not asking for exact average but guesstimation, is that too difficult?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to know something about the variance of the set. Even to guesstimate. Using your example, what if all the students got 14.5 out of 25? What if 4 students got 14.5 and the rest got 25/25? You can see how the average can wildly fluctuate between those 2 cases.

With 80 students taking a test, you may be able to get away with Cental Limit Theorem, but that's a stretch if you ask me.

EDIT: I guess based on worst/best case scenarios, you could get an upper/lower bound for the mean.

- **Lower Bound:** 3 people get 0, everyone else gets 14.5
- **Upper Bound:** 4 people get 14.5, rest get 25/25

So for your example the mean would be somewhere between 13.775 and 24.225, but I'm guessing you wanted something a bit more specific than that :p